# ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token) from XML website

Tags: python, xml

I am getting a `ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)` from this:

```
url = '%s' % steamFriend['profileurl']
tree = ET.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

Some more info:

The website is http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198152260508?xml=1 and this is it's XML tree:

```
<profile>
<steamID64>76561198152260508</steamID64>
<steamID>
<![CDATA[ H@!nE ]]>
</steamID>
<onlineState>offline</onlineState>
<stateMessage>
<![CDATA[ Last Online: ]]>
</stateMessage>
<privacyState>private</privacyState>
<visibilityState>1</visibilityState>
<avatarIcon>
<![CDATA[
http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/be/be7cf633afe1094e4b8dd834321af369a4a37d10.jpg
]]>
</avatarIcon>
<avatarMedium>
<![CDATA[
http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/be/be7cf633afe1094e4b8dd834321af369a4a37d10_medium.jpg
]]>
</avatarMedium>
<avatarFull>
<![CDATA[
http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/be/be7cf633afe1094e4b8dd834321af369a4a37d10_full.jpg
]]>
</avatarFull>
<vacBanned>0</vacBanned>
<tradeBanState>None</tradeBanState>
<isLimitedAccount>1</isLimitedAccount>
</profile>
```

Can anyone explain what the error is and how to fix it? Sorry I'm relatively new to python, and I'm really confused as to why my code isn't working.

Comment: The string works for me with ElementTree.

Comment: Really? I'm using Flask to run the code above, and it's giving me that error.

Comment: I have this import statement as well: `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

Comment: Maybe we have different versions (for me, ET.VERSION is 1.3.0), but it worked for me. Perhaps earlier versions were confused by CDATA sections.